# SQL Joining Strings for a path referencing external file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I'm trying to join some strings together to define a path - for example, given $(name) = "PATH", I want `:r .\PathOne\PATH.sql`.  The query fails at the first `:r` due to `Syntax Error`.  If I hardcode the paths, and leave `$(name)` in the conditionals, it works as expected.  It's just the string construction for the path that's failing for some reason.

```
 IF '$(name)' LIKE 'TEST%'
 BEGIN
   :r .\PathOne\'$(name)'.sql
 END
 IF '$(name)' NOT LIKE 'TEST%'
 BEGIN
   :r .\PathTwo\'$(name)'.sql
 END
```

How do I go about joining strings for a path in SQL?  Naming the files directly works.

Comment: Are you sure you set your query window to SQLCMD mode? WHere did you define the name variable?

Comment: Please provide the desired result and the result you get

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes it is - this is defined and works elsewhere, just not in the string construction.

Comment: @FLICKER - updated.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - this flow works as I want it to if I hardcode the paths.  All I need is help constructing the paths with the string - even the `IF '$(name)'` works just as I want it to.  I just can't get the string paths working.

Comment: Try `:r ".\PathOne\"$(name)".sql"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose the hardcoded Parts of the path inside a double quote and your variables without any space next to hardcoded part for Constructing a path, For example

```
:setvar filename "test"
:setvar root "D:\temp"
:r  $(root)"\test\"$(filename)".sql"
```

will result in path like

> D:\temp\test\test.sql

To resolve your problem try something like this

```
:r ".\PathOne\"$(name)".sql"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I know that it may not sound intuitive, but try putting the path in double-quotes, like below. This works on my machine. Without the double-quotes, I get the same failure as you.

```
:setvar name "test"

if '$(name)' like 'test%'
begin
    :r "c:\temp\test1\"$(name).sql
end
else if '$(name)' not like 'test%'
begin
    :r "c:\temp\test2\"$(name).sql
end
```